# How can I use gulpfile.js from another JS file by command gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to use my compiling scripts in different projects as a submodule of GIT modules.

I added the submodule into a directory named `build`, and there is a `gulpfile.js` in the `build` dir.

I created another `gulpfile.js` in the root dir of the project, then using this `gulpfile.js` to invoke the real `gulpfile.js` in `build` dir.

After I running the `gulp` command, I got an error message that told me that "Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile".

I don't want to manage any dependence in each project that going to use this `build`, I just want to find out a way to invoke the real `gulpfile`.

What shall I do? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide enough source code to be able to reproduce the error, in order to make this a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to either set a gulp cli config file .gulp.json with a property setting the path to your custom gulpfile, or use `gulp --gulpfile [path]`. More on this on the github readme page of gulp-cli https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks very much, it is useful to me by using `gulp --gulpfile [path]`, but I can't understand how to use the `.gulp.json` file even though I read the document for several times. I tried to add a `.gulp.json` file in the dir of my project but It didn't work.